# wpf master detail implementation TWO WAY BINDING REQUIRES PATH OR XPATH

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls, wpfdatagrid

Allready have a two classes in master detail schema,

the master class has a collection of detail master, and need (want) to perform all crude options inline.

Classes:

```
public partial class Items
{
    public Items()
    {
        this.Detail = new HashSet<Detail>();
    }

    public decimal NumIdConcepto { get; set; }
    public string StrDescripcionConcepto { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Detail> Detail { get; set; }
}

public partial class Detail
{
    public int IntTipoAsociado { get; set; }
    public decimal NumIdConcepto { get; set; }

    public virtual Items Items { get; set; }
    public virtual Master Master { get; set; }
}

public partial class Master
{
    public Master()
    {
        this.Detail = new HashSet<Detail>();
    }

    public int IntTipoAsociado { get; set; }
    public string StrDescripcionTipoAsociado { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Detail> Detail { get; set; }
}
```

For editing purposes and limitations of EF generator must perform a conversion 
    from **HashSet** to **ObservableCollection** for Detail collection of Master

```
public class listToObservableCollection : BaseConverter, IValueConverter
{
    public HashSet<Detail> JustForPath { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<Detail> JustForPathObservable { get; set; }

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        HashSet<Detail> observableList = (HashSet<Detail>)value;
        JustForPathObservable = new ObservableCollection<Detail>(observableList);
        return JustForPathObservable;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        JustForPath = (HashSet<Detail>)value;
        return JustForPath;
    }
}

public abstract class BaseConverter : MarkupExtension
{
    public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        return this;
    }
}
```

With this structure I want to generate a DataGrid wich allow me to add, delete, and edit Detail In line, Don't want to call another forms

Like this:

[image]

My XAML code look like this:

```
<Window
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:ViewModels="clr-namespace:Contratos.ViewModels" x:Class="Contratos.Views.TipoAsociado"
    xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity" 
    xmlns:cmd="clr-namespace:GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Command;assembly=GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Extras.WPF45"
    xmlns:l="clr-namespace:Recursos;assembly=Recursos"
    Title="{Binding Title}" Height="Auto" Width="Auto">
<Window.DataContext>
    <ViewModels:TipoAsociadoVM/>
</Window.DataContext>
<Window.Resources>
    <l:listToObservableCollection x:Key="listoToObservable"/>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <DataGrid Grid.Row="1" 
              ItemsSource="{Binding Master}"  
              AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
              SelectionMode="Single"
              GridLinesVisibility="Vertical"
              CanUserAddRows="True"
              CanUserDeleteRows="True"
              x:Name="GridTipoAsociado"
              Margin="5" SelectionChanged="GridTipoAsociado_SelectionChanged">
        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
            <i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged">
                <cmd:EventToCommand Command="{Binding _ICommandSelectionChange}"
                                    PassEventArgsToCommand="True"/>
            </i:EventTrigger>
        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Description" x:Name="Description">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Label Content="{Binding StrDescripcionTipoAsociado}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBox Text="{Binding StrDescripcionTipoAsociado }"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <DataGrid Grid.Row="1" 
                        ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Detail,Converter={StaticResource listoToObservable},Mode=TwoWay}"
                        DisplayMemberPath="StrDescripcionConcepto"
                        AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
                        IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"
                        SelectionMode="Single"
                        SelectionUnit="Cell"
                        GridLinesVisibility="Vertical"
                        CanUserAddRows="True"
                        CanUserDeleteRows="True"                            
                        x:Name="GridItems"
                        Margin="20,5,5,5">
                    <DataGrid.Columns>
                        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Items">
                            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <Label Content="{Binding Items.StrDescripcionConcepto}"/>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <!--
                                        Here is my problem How can i to bind to the propper values to perform Editing 
                                        Without having this exception "TWO WAY BINDING REQUIRES PATH OR XPATH"  when try to update DETAIL items:
                                    -->     
                                    <TextBox Text="{Binding Items.StrDescripcionConcepto}"/>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                    </DataGrid.Columns>
                </DataGrid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
    </DataGrid>
</Grid>
</Window>
```

Now, I need help on how to build a propper CellEditingTemplate, to allow me edit all the changes that i need ?

Here is my problem How can i to bind to the propper values to perform Editing 
Without having this exception "TWO WAY BINDING REQUIRES PATH OR XPATH"  when try to update DETAIL items?

NOTE: I don't want to create **new Items**, here, Just attach it to **Detail**

Comment: HashSets dont support editing because it doesn't implement IList. You need a Collection that implements IList to do editing.

Comment: Yes, I know that. Thats why in my question include **"For editing purposes and limitations of EF generator must perform a conversion from HashSet to ObservableCollection for Detail collection of Master"**. I need to know how to set propper bindings for adding new items to Detail class. Tks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally found my problem and of course the solution.

The binding must be relative to the datacontext of the window instead **relative** to it's parent, in this case **DataGrid**

I'm redefining the datacontext of the window as a static resource, then I reuse it for my elements that need access to the global properties of my model, Grid  and CellEditingTemplate

```
<Window.Resources>
    <ViewModels:ViewModel x:Key="ViewDataContext"/>
</Window.Resources>

<!-- Here I use Static resource as Data context -->
<Grid DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource ResourceKey=ViewDataContext}}">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Tipo de asociado" x:Name="TipoUsuarioSeleccionado">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Label Content="{Binding SomeElement}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                   <DataTemplate>
                     <!-- Again I use Static resource as Data context -->
                     <Grid Height="130" DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource ViewDataContext}}">
                           <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                               <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
                               <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
                           </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                           <TextBox x:Name="Filtro" Text="{Binding SomeInViewModel}"/>
                           <ListView Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding ListaItems}">
                              <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                                  <DataTemplate>
                                     <TextBlock Text="{Binding SomeinVM}"/>
                                  </DataTemplate>
                              </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                           </ListView>
                     </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
             </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

The error, "TWO WAY BINDING REQUIRES PATH OR XPATH", can also be thrown if your binding path is incorrect.  For example, if your property is called "DisplayName", but you have used "Name" in the XAML binding expression.

In this case, you will also get additional information from the VS debugger in the Output window if you're looking for it.  Or, if like me, you don't remember to look there, maybe you'll spend half a day scouring the internet before realizing you made a assumption followed by a typo.

So in my case, this error meant that the binding path was incorrect.  Perhaps your Path is missing and you need to specify it (hence, the abundance of `Binding Path=.`  vs. `Binding` advice).  Or perhaps you made a typo and need to double check your assumptions regarding property names.

Rule #1 with WPF binding debugging.  Keep that Output window open at ALL times.